# Angularjs Kendo Grid Server side Filters

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to develop kendo grid using Asp.NET MVC and Angularjs. my code is as mentioned below.

**Index.cshtml**

```
<div ng-controller="telerikGridController">
<kendo-grid options="mainGridOptions">
    <div k-detail-template>
        <kendo-tabstrip>
            <ul>
                <li class="k-state-active">Orders</li>
                <li>Contact information</li>
            </ul>
            <div>
                <div kendo-grid k-options="detailGridOptions(dataItem)"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>Country: <input ng-model="dataItem.Country" /></li>
                    <li>City: <input ng-model="dataItem.City"/></li>
                    <li>Address: {{dataItem.Address}}</li>
                    <li>Home phone: {{dataItem.Phone}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </kendo-tabstrip>
    </div>
</kendo-grid>
</div>
```

**AngularJS controller** (telerikGridController)

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['kendo.directives', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('telerikGridController', ['$scope', function telerikGridController($scope) {

    $scope.mainGridOptions = {
        dataSource: {
            type: "json",
            transport: {
                read: "Grid/Departments"
            },
            pageSize: 2,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverSorting: true
        },
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        dataBound: function() {
            this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
        },            
        columns: [
                {
                    field: "DepartmentName",
                    title: "Department Name",
                    width: "120px"
                }, {
                    field: "Country",
                    title: "Country",
                    width: "120px"
                }, {
                    field: "City",
                    width: "120px"
                }, {
                    field: "Phone",
                    width: "120px"
                }, {
                    field: "Description"
                }
        ]

    };

    $scope.detailGridOptions = function(dataItem) {
        return {
            dataSource: {
                type: "json",
                transport: {
                    read: "Grid/GetEmployees"
                },
                serverPaging: true,
                serverSorting: true,
                serverFiltering: true,
                pageSize: 2,
                filter: { field: "DeptId", operator: "eq", value: dataItem.DeptId }
            },
            scrollable: false,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: true,
            filterable:true,
            columns: [
                { field: "FirstName", title: "First Name", width: "56px" },
                { field: "LastName", title: "Last Name", width: "110px" },
                { field: "Address", title: "Address" },
                { field: "Phone", title: "Phone", width: "190px" }
            ]
        };
    }
 }
]);
```

ASP.NET MVC Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using KendoGridApp.Models;
using Kendo.Mvc;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;

namespace KendoGridApp.Controllers
{
  public class GridController : Controller
  {
    List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
    List<Department> deptList = new List<Department>();

    public GridController()
    {
        Employee employe = new Employee();
        employe.FirstName = "First Name";
        employe.LastName = "Last Name";
        employe.Phone = "+92 302 8888 777";
        employe.Address = " Pakistan";
        employe.DeptId = 1;



        var employe2 = new Employee();
        employe2.FirstName = "First Name 2";
        employe2.LastName = "Last Name 2";
        employe2.Phone = "+92 333 4444 779";
        employe2.Address = "UAE";
        employe2.DeptId = 2;

        var employe3 = new Employee();
        employe3.FirstName = "First Name 3";
        employe3.LastName = "Last Name 3";
        employe3.Phone = "+92 302 4444 779";
        employe3.Address = "Sydney,Australia";
        employe3.DeptId = 3;

        var employe4 = new Employee();
        employe4.FirstName = "First Name 4";
        employe4.LastName = "Last Name 4";
        employe4.Phone = "+92 302 4444 999";
        employe4.Address = "Sydney, Australia";
        employe4.DeptId = 4;

        var employe5 = new Employee();
        employe5.FirstName = "First Name 5";
        employe5.LastName = "Last Name 5";
        employe5.Phone = "+92 302 1111 779";
        employe5.Address = "Dubai, UAE";
        employe5.DeptId = 5;

        var employe6 = new Employee();
        employe6.FirstName = "First Name 6";
        employe6.LastName = "Last Name 6";
        employe6.Phone = "+92 302 0000 779";
        employe6.Address = "Dehli, India";
        employe6.DeptId = 6;

        employees.Add(employe);
        employees.Add(employe2);
        employees.Add(employe3);
        employees.Add(employe4);
        employees.Add(employe5);
        employees.Add(employe6);
    }
    // GET: Grid
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetEmployees(DataSourceRequest command)
    {

        int deptId = Convert.ToInt16(Request.Params["filter[filters][0][value]"]);

        employees = employees.Where(x => x.DeptId == deptId).ToList();

        return Json(employees, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Departments()
    {
        Department dept = new Department();
        dept.DeptId = 1;
        dept.DepartmentName = "Information Technology";
        dept.Phone = "+1 111 111 111";
        dept.Country = "Pakistan";
        dept.City = "Lahore";
        dept.Description = "This is Description Text 1";

        Department dept2 = new Department();
        dept2.DeptId = 2;
        dept2.DepartmentName = "Mechnical Engineering";
        dept2.Phone = "+1 222 111 111";
        dept2.Country = "India";
        dept2.City = "Dehli";
        dept2.Description = "This is Description Text 2";

        Department dept3 = new Department();
        dept3.DeptId = 3;
        dept3.DepartmentName = "Civil Engineering";
        dept3.Phone = "+1 111 000 111";
        dept3.Country = "Pakistan";
        dept3.City = "Islamabad";
        dept3.Description = "This is Description Text 3";

        Department dept4 = new Department();
        dept4.DeptId = 4;
        dept4.DepartmentName = "Radiology";
        dept4.Phone = "+1 111 222 000";
        dept4.Country = "UAE";
        dept4.City = "Dubai";
        dept4.Description = "This is Description Text 4";

        Department dept5 = new Department();
        dept5.DeptId = 5;
        dept5.DepartmentName = "Defence";
        dept5.Phone = "+1 555 888 999";
        dept5.Country = "Australia";
        dept5.City = "Sydney";
        dept5.Description = "This is Description Text 5";

        Department dept6 = new Department();
        dept6.DeptId = 6;
        dept6.DepartmentName = "Socialogy";
        dept6.Phone = "+1 555 777 000";
        dept6.Country = "United States";
        dept6.City = "New York";
        dept6.Description = "This is Description Text 6";

        deptList.Add(dept);
        deptList.Add(dept2);
        deptList.Add(dept3);
        deptList.Add(dept4);
        deptList.Add(dept5);
        deptList.Add(dept6);

        return Json(deptList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
  }
}
```

Issue:

Issue i am facing is in GetEmployees JsonResult function, DataSourceRequest command has always Filters = null. Whereas, my request is showing requests like,

**Query String Parameters:**

```
take:2
skip:0
page:1
pageSize:2
filter[logic]:and
filter[filters][0][field]:DeptId
filter[filters][0][operator]:eq
filter[filters][0][value]:3
```

and **Request link** is like,

```
GetEmployees?take=2&skip=0&page=1&pageSize=2&filter%5Blogic%5D=and&filter%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=DeptId&filter%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Boperator%5D=eq&filter%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=3
```

currently I am able to get filters in server side using HttpRequestWrapper as mentioned below in GetEmployees JsonResult

```
int deptId = Convert.ToInt16(Request.Params["filter[filters][0][value]"]);
```

but is there any better approach to get these filters at server side? for example using DataSourceRequest?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is works for me for server side filtering. Try add `[DataSourceRequest]` tag before variable type to solve your filter binding issue and to handle filtering you can use extension `ToDataSourceResult()` which provided by `Kendo.Mvc.Extensions`.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    // removed for brevity 
    // .......

    return Json(viewModels.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: DataSourceRequest Filters is still null. can you provide any example using angularjs and asp.net mvc?

Comment: Try add `serverFiltering:true` in parent grid option

Comment: what i think is i may need to use parameterMap? i yes, how i will use that?

Comment: i am done with this issue but now i am facing paging issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837727/angularjs-kendo-grid-paging-is-always-zero Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Use `type: "aspnetmvc-ajax",` instead of `type: "json",` in your dataSource and use the `[DataSourceRequest]` attribute in your controller.

`public JsonResult GetEmployees([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest command)`

Comment: i tried, but this is not working, Filters are still null

Comment: what i think i may need to use parameterMap. If yes, how i will use that?

Comment: i am done with this issue but now i am facing paging issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837727/angularjs-kendo-grid-paging-is-always-zero Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Finally, After hammering my head long i found the solution.

In my Code above mentioned,

**Replace in  $scope.detailGridOptions:** (telerikGridController)

```
 dataSource: {
   type: "json",
   transport: {
        read: "Grid/GetEmployees"
   },
   pageSize: 2,
   serverPaging: true,
   serverSorting: true
 },
```

**With:**

```
dataSource: {
    type: "aspnetmvc-ajax",
    transport: {
        read: "Grid/GetEmployees",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
      },
 schema:
     {
       data: "Data",
       total: "Total",
       errors: "Errors"
      },
   pageSize: 2,
   serverPaging: true,
   serverSorting: true
 },
```

**And in Asp.NET MVC controller:**

**Replace**

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetEmployees(DataSourceRequest command)
```

**With**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetEmployees(DataSourceRequest command)
```

And Everything will start working file. you will be receiving Filters/Sort etc everyting in DataSourceRequest object.